# Python Regex error

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of file paths, with the file name containing something I need to retrieve. `C:\PATH\PATH\PATH\PATH\THE_THING_I_NEED.xslx`

Using [Pythex](http://pythex.org/) I created the regular expression and it picks exactly what I want. Which is everything between `\` and `.xslx`. Below is the code and error I get:

```
import re
files = ['C:\\PATH\\PATH\\PATH\\thing1.xlsx', 'C:\\PATH\\PATH\\PATH\\PATH\\thing2.xlsx']

pattern = re.compile('(?<=\\)?[a-zA-Z]+(?=\.xlsx)')
for x in files:
    matches =re.findall(pattern, x)
    print(matches)

#error i get below   
error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0
```

So following the error i added an extra `)` and it works:

```
pattern = re.compile('(?<=\\))?[a-zA-Z]+(?=\.xlsx)')
#                           ^ added right there
```

What exactly is that extra `)` doing? Pythex doesn't seem to need it and to my eye, it seems unnecessary

Comment: That is why it is recommended to use raw string literals when defining regex in Python.

Comment: You don't need an extra ), you need an extra \\.

Comment: If you're trying to extract data from file paths, consider using the functions in `os.path`, which exist for exactly that purpose. `os.path.splitext(os.path.split('C:\\PATH\\PATH\\PATH\\thing1.xlsx')[1])[0]` gives you `"thing1"`.

Comment: The lookbehind is not necessary since you are using `re.findall`. Just use a capturing group around the pattern you need to extract. Your filenames also contain digits. Use `pattern = re.compile(r'\\([^\\]+)\.xlsx')`, see [**this online demo**](https://ideone.com/Fji8Je).

Comment: You need to escape the backslash for regex so you get `\\ `. Now comes the next layer. To create those two backslashes in Python you have to escape each of them in your string literal leading to `\\\\ `. That's why you should use a raw string (which doesn't do escaping), as Wiktor said: `r'\\ '`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool. I'd recommend the `os` module for what you want to accomplish:

```
import os

files = ['C:\\PATH\\PATH\\PATH\\thing1.xlsx', 'C:\\PATH\\PATH\\PATH\\PATH\\thing2.xlsx']
for file in files:
    base = os.path.basename(file)
    print(os.path.splitext(base)[0])
```

This will print exactly what you want:

> ```
> thing1
> thing2
> ```

You can also wrap this as a one-liner inside a function as stated in comments:

```
import os


def get_filename(files):
    return [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0] for file in files]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = ['C:\\PATH\\PATH\\PATH\\thing1.xlsx', 'C:\\PATH\\PATH\\PATH\\PATH\\thing2.xlsx']
    print(get_filename(files))
```